# Wordpress API question

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I check if a category exists, and if exists, return the ID; if not, create the category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Wordpress [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category), [`get_cat_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID) and [`wp_create_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_category) method.

```
<?php
  $CategoryName = "books";
  if(is_category($CategoryName))
        $categoryID = get_cat_ID($CategoryName);
  else
        $categoryID = wp_create_category($CategoryName);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

See wp_create_category().

```
include( "../../wordpress/wp-config.php" );
include( "../../wordpress/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php" );

$cat_id = wp_create_category( "TESTINGLOL" );
echo "created = {$cat_id}\n";
echo "returned = " . get_cat_ID( "TESTINGLOL" );
```

Output should go like:

```
created = 37450 returned = 37450
```

Note that this isn't very efficient, but, does the job.

Comment: Note that this method doesn't require checking whether the category already exists - if it does, wp_create_category() will simply return its cat ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
create_category_if_not_exist($category_name, $echo = true) {
    $id = wp_insert_term( $category_name, 'category');
    if ( $echo ) return $id;
    return $id;
}
```

Nice all in one function for doing the trick.  `$category_name` would need to be the category slug though.

`wp_insert_term()` takes care of checking if the category already exists in the database.  It will return the `$id` of the category if it exists and will return the $id of the newly created category if it doesn't pre-exist.